# how to detect if there is a chromecast device connect to the Android Tv?

Tags: android, android-tv

Hi I try to detect if some kind of Chromecast device is trying to connect to the TV. More that building a receiver I want to detect if whatever Chromecast sender is trying to connect to the Tv.